# Sinusoidal steady-state analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, laplace-transform, steady-state

Find the Transfer function of the given circuit in the frequency domain.The problem here is that the equations of this circuit become complicated by finding equal Z of R,C,L (right side of the circuit) in frequency domain which is ((Ls+R)/(LCs^2+RCs+1)). The next step is to apply voltage divider for Z and R which leads to Vc/VS.(as my friends mentioned in the answer part),then another voltage divider between R and L (Right side of circuit) which finally result in T.S.

firstly i am not sure that this approach is correct.

secondly ,if i calculate H(s) how should i use the given information (relation between Omega and other components) to get Vo(t). [image: The given problem]

Comment: Yes, they do become complicated so where are you stuck?

Comment: *why* are they hard? It's hard to help you if we don't know what you're stuck with. To me, this looks like a pretty trivial linear network that with a single transformation can be simplified to a voltage divider, and then it's just plugging in numbers...

Comment: Oh wait, this is a copy of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/506234/sinusoidal-steady-state-circuit-analysis-how-should-i-solve-it . Don't do that.

Comment: In the process of simplifying the capacitor, inductor and resistor to \$Z\$, you have *lost* the node where the output was originally measured. \$V_0\$ was originally measured across the right most resistor. in the *simplified* figure, \$V_0\$ is effectively measured across the inductor-resistor combination. (You have noted it in your edited question). I think you shouldn't name the result you got as \$V_0 / V_s\$. You can name it as \$V_c / V_s\$.

Comment: yes,that's correct .So it needs another voltage divider .

Comment: I try to explain my work with detail to show my attempt and i think this question can help other people too because it covers a wide range of knowledge in Electrical Engineering domain,I hope my friends(@MarcusMüller, @Voltage Spike) reconsider .Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *until Z of right side of the circuit :(LS+R)/(LCS^2+RCS+1)*

Well your almost there now that you have the parallel impedance of C, L and the right-hand R: -

$$Z = \dfrac{R+sL}{s^2LC+sRC+1}$$

Form the potential divider with the left-hand resistor to get: -

$$\dfrac{V_{C}}{V_{IN}} = \dfrac{\dfrac{R+sL}{s^2LC+sRC+1}}{\dfrac{R+sL}{s^2LC+sRC+1} + R}$$

Then multiply by top and bottom by \$(s^2LC+sRC+1)\$ to get this: -

$$\dfrac{V_{C}}{V_{IN}} = \dfrac{R + sL}{R+sL +R(s^2LC+sRC+1)}$$

$$\dfrac{V_{C}}{V_{IN}} = \dfrac{R + sL}{R+sL +s^2LCR+sR^2C+R}$$

$$\dfrac{V_{C}}{V_{IN}} = \dfrac{R + sL}{s^2LCR+s(R^2C+L)+2R}$$

To get \$V_{OUT}\$ we have this: -

$$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_C} = \dfrac{R}{sL+R}$$

Therefore: -

$$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = \dfrac{R}{s^2LCR+s(R^2C+L)+2R}$$

$$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = \dfrac{1}{s^2LC+s(RC+\frac{L}{R})+2}$$

Then drill down further if you want: -

$$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\frac{2}{LC}}{s^2 + s(\frac{1}{CR}+\frac{R}{L})+\frac{2}{LC}}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks my friend ,now that we have T.S how i should use the given information and calculate Vo(t) @Andy aka

Comment: What is Vin(t)? If it is a step then multiply the TF by 1/s (the laplace of a step) and do the inverse laplace (with a few hurdles of partial fractions) or find a table of inverses.

Comment: and when should i use info given by the  question,

Comment: vin is (v sin omega* t)

Comment: @RasoulAkbari were you not given the information about the time related input voltage?

Comment: Do you know the laplace of sin(wt)?

Comment: yes , sir ,I'm sorry if i bother you with my question

Comment: I'm unsure what else you need to know. You multiply the TF with laplace(sin(wt)) and then try and do a reverse laplace.

Comment: @RasoulAkbari if we're done here now please consider formal acceptance of my answer. It's easy to do = just press the symbol below the downvote triangle at the top left of this answer. Or, ask another question by commenting.

Comment: of course , my friend ,but it could be the best if we put the full answer.

Comment: @RasoulAkbari yes but only you know the full answer.